# Is there any method to see if keyboard is hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example, I have a text field, a cancel button, some free space on the view controller and a keyboard with the globe key.

If I tap text field - keyboard appears. If I tap cancel button or free space - keyboards dissappears.

If I tap globe key - one keyboard layout dissappears and another appears.

Question: is there any read-only method that returns if keyboard is hidden or shown?

Comment: Listen for the keyboard notifications defined in `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIResponder's `isFirstResponder`.  If a user touches on a text field and `isFirstResponder` returns `YES`, you know the keyboard is currently being displayed.

Note: this does not work on hardware keyboards.

[UIResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html)

Comment: What about iPad? I don't think the keyboard automatically dismisses.